# Restart a velocity.js animation loop after stopping

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to restart a velocity animation after it has been stopped.

Is there a velocity only way without applying a new animation with same properties again?

```
var box = $('.box');
box.velocity({rotateZ:'360deg'}, {duration:1000, loop:true});

// That's a dummy to explain what I'm trying  to do
setTimeout(function{
  box.velocity('stop');

  setTimeout(function(){
    box.velocity('START ORIGIN ANIMATION AGAIN');
  });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible!

```
function Start() {

    var box = $('.box');

    DoRotation();

    $('#GoBtn').click(function() {

        box.velocity('stop').velocity({rotateZ:'0deg'}, {duration:1});

        setTimeout(DoRotation, 1000);

    });

    function DoRotation() {

         box.velocity({rotateZ:'360deg'}, {duration:1000, loop:true});
    }
}

$(Start);
```

And here's a jsFiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/uy6578an/

I use something like this where I start and restart an amination and it works no problem, take a look at here to see it running on the timer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKEW02J3usA

Comment: This technically works, but its not Pause/Resume, this only STOPS and RESTARTS the animation. The answer by @forethought is the correct answer for PAUSE/RESUME.

Answer (score 2):

I know, it is a bit late response to the question. Velocity.js adds Pause / Resume (per element or global) feature to it since 1.4 version.

You can use the feature like this;

```
$element.velocity('pause');

or 

$element.velocity('resume');
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done with a setInterval() method.

```
var box = $('.box');
setInterval(function() {
    box.velocity({translateY: '-100%'}, 5000);
    box.velocity('reverse', {duration: 1});
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is a `pause()`/`resume()` features, then no, it's currently not implemented in Velocity.

You'll have to manually restart your animation and you can use force-feeding to restart it from where you last stopped it.

Answer (score 0):

As ydaniv mentioned, there is no pause / resume functionality.

However, you might have some success looking into [Tweene](http://tweene.com/) as it extendeds Velocity.js and it's functionality.

To quote the Tweene docs "With Tweene you have now play(), pause(), resume(), reverse() and restart() methods for all supported libraries, for both tweens and timelines."